# scope of if statement in javascript compared to python

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in react where i want to do :

```
   renderPost(data) {
        const dateStr = new Date(data.pub_date).toLocaleString();
        const img='empty'
        if (data.header_image_url.url!=null) {
            const img=data.header_image_url.url}
        else {
            const img="/app/frontend/img.png"}
        return (
            <div className="card mb-4">
            <Link to={`/post/${data.id}`}> <img src={img} className="card-img-top" alt=""/> </Link>
```

But it's not working like python : the const img inside the {} in the if and else statements dont take effect and dont override my const variable declaration above.

How can i do that ?

Comment: a) you seem to have a misunderstanding about what `const` means, b) you are redeclaring the (block-scoped) variable over and over, c) a javascript tutorial may be useful to read, e.g. https://javascript.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here.

**You can't change the value of a `const`**. That's the whole point of `const`s! If you want to change it, use `let`.

Declaring a variable in a different scope [**shadows**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable in the wider scope. It doesn't overwrite it. Don't use `const` (or `let`) inside the block.

---

There is a school of thought which says you should avoid overwriting variables in favour of code structures where they are assigned in a single place. This can make code more readable.

In this case, each branch of the `if` does nothing except make an assignment to the same place.

This is the ideal place to use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
const img = data.header_image_url.url != null
     ? data.header_image_url.url
     : "/app/frontend/img.png";
```

… or a [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
const img = data.header_image_url.url ?? "/app/frontend/img.png";
```

Comment: thanks it makes sense...it's not the same approach as in python. what about using var?

Comment: `var` is essentially `let` but looser and with problems. There's no reason to use it in 2022 other than if you are targetting Internet Explorer.